# How to extract data (Download) from IBM Watson notebook

Tags: ibm-watson

I have an instance of Pandas dataframe in a notebook runs in IBM Watson. I need to download the dataframe as a CSV file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File read and File write python operations works in the notebook environment. If you want to run a system command all you have to do is run a command after `!` to list the file you can just do

`!ls -la`

So my approach was to create a file in the local storage and encode the file in base64 and create a download link

from IPython.display import HTML
import base64

```
def create_download_link( dataframe, title = "Download CSV file", filename = "myout222.csv"):  
    csv = dataframe.to_csv() # create the csv 
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode()) # encode the file 
    payload = b64.decode() # set the payload
    html = '<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" target="_blank">{title}</a>'
    html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
    return HTML(html) # returning the link
```

Now call the function `create_download_link(your_dataframe)`

instead of a dataframe you can download any file by just reading the file and encoding the file

Since the system commands are working you can also upload the files into a separate server using `curl`, And also you can download files into the local storage by `wget`